# Add a method into a nested exported struct

Tags: go

I'd like to add a method into the nested exported struct that is used in exported struct.

I have a `[]*ldap.Entry` type returned by the [ldap.Search().Entries](https://github.com/go-ldap/ldap/blob/master/search.go#L193)

`ldap.Entry` type consists of `Attributes []*EntryAttribute`. My goal is to add an extra method into the `ldap.EntryAttribute`, e.g. `MarshalJSON`

I can add an extra code directly into the `ldap` package and it will work as I expect. But it is a dirty way:

```
// EntryAttribute holds a single attribute
type newEntryAttribute struct {
        // Name is the name of the attribute
        Name string
        // Values contain the string values of the attribute
        Values []string
        // ByteValues contain the raw values of the attribute
        ByteValues [][]byte
}

// Print outputs a human-readable description
func (e EntryAttribute) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
        b := newEntryAttribute(e)
        b.ByteValues = nil
        return json.Marshal(b)
}
```

How can I do that in a more elegant way?

Comment: You cannot add methods to imported types and you cannot add methods to unnamed types (not sure whether that is what you meant by nested).

Comment: You can only define a method on a type in the same package in which that type is defined.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can come is to create the method on your own type, which embeds the EntryAttribute type. Something like this:

```
package mine

import "github.com/go-ldap/ldap""

type EntryAttribute {
    ldap.EntryAttribute
}

func (e EntryAttribute) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    // ...
}
```

But then, you *must* use *your* type, not the original type, everywhere in your program.

Answer (score -1):

So far I have found the solution below. It is not elegant, but it doesn't require the package modification.

```
type myEntry struct {
        *ldap.Entry
        Attributes []*myEntryAttribute
}

type myEntryAttribute struct {
        *ldap.EntryAttribute
}

func (a *myEntryAttribute) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
        return json.Marshal(struct {
                Name   string
                Values []string 
        }{Name: a.Name, Values: a.Values})
}

func ldapEntry2myEntry(t interface{}) interface{} {
        switch e := t.(type) {
        case []*ldap.Entry:
                var res []interface{}
                for _, v := range e {
                        res = append(res, ldapEntry2myEntry(v))
                }
                return res
        case *ldap.Entry:
                var att []*myEntryAttribute
                for _, a := range e.Attributes {
                        att = append(att, &myEntryAttribute{a})
                }
                return &myEntry{e, att}
        }
        return nil
}

... ... ...

data, err := json.Marshal(ldapEntry2myEntry(sr.Entries))
if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error")
}
fmt.Printf("%s\n", data)

// or only one element

data, err := json.Marshal(ldapEntry2myEntry(sr.Entries[0]))
if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error")
}
fmt.Printf("%s\n", data)
```